# echo the output of a <textarea> into html using php

Tags: php

I am echoing the below using nicedit.com

```
<img src=http://images/14fc272d-131b-47ce-b452-9cd47a4a3846.jpg>

<iframe width=420 height=315 src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/LBBqOTd5qzE frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It ends up as just as code.

I tried `nl2br()` but its still text.

Using htmlspecialchars()

```
&lt;img src=http://14fc272d-131b-47ce-b452-9cd47a4a3846.jpg&gt;<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>&lt;iframe width=420 height=315 src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/LBBqOTd5qzE frameborder=0 allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</div>
```

Any ideas how to convert them into the said images/iframe videos etc.

Comment: Try to use `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert special chars to entities. Also, start quoting tags' attributes:

```
<img src="http://images/14fc272d-131b-47ce-b452-9cd47a4a3846.jpg">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LBBqOTd5qzE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You may also want to back `allowfullscreen` with `webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen` as well.

**EDIT**

> I am echoing from `<textarea>`

Ok, you then already got entities (your question wasn't clear enough). You need the opposite to `htmlspecialchars()` then, which is `html_entity_decode()` or `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

Comment: It works fine. You echo it into `<textarea>` then it is not processed but taken literaly as just text. You cannot have images etc in `textarea`

Comment: I am echoing from <textarea>.  You will see I am using NiceEdit.com RTE

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to show that codes on Browser. without executing it..
It could be your solution:-

```
<pre>
<img src=http://images/14fc272d-131b-47ce-b452-9cd47a4a3846.jpg>

<iframe width=420 height=315 src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/LBBqOTd5qzE frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>
</pre>
```